# EF context - with flexibility OnConfiguring throws errors

Tags: entity-framework-core

Trying to build a docker friendly application that allows the user to work with the Database that works for their hardware and setup.

So I've got a EfContext that grabs the requested database type from environment variables and tries do use.

I've got api's and repeating services but the problem is SqLite in memory is the only one that initializes fast enough not to throw exceptions.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context instance
> while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside
> 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if
> a second operation is started on this context instance before a previous operation
> completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
   private ILogger<Context> _logger;

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options, ILogger<Context> logger) : base(options) {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public DbSet<Callback> Callbacks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)  {         
        switch(TheConfiguration.DatabaseType) {
            case DatabaseType.FileSystem:
                Setup_FileSystem(optionsBuilder);
                break;
            case DatabaseType.SqlLiteInMemory:
                Setup_SqlLiteInMemory(optionsBuilder);
                break;
            case DatabaseType.SqlLite:
                Setup_SqlLite(optionsBuilder);
                break;
        }               
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Callback>()
            .ToTable("callbacks");
    }

    private void Setup_FileSystem(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt) {
        opt.UseFileBaseContextDatabase(location: "/Data");
    }

    private void Setup_SqlLiteInMemory(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt) {
        var _connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=InMemorySample;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared");
        _connection.Open();
        opt.UseSqlite(connection: _connection);
    }

    private void Setup_SqlLite(DbContextOptionsBuilder opt) {
        var _connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=/Data/sqLite/callbacks.db");
        _connection.Open();
        opt.UseSqlite(connection: _connection);
        Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

and in case i'm doing something strange with initialization:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Context>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<RepeatingService>();
```

If I'm doing this in a profoundly dumb way I'm happy for help [GitHub - repo](https://github.com/hurricanepkt/SmartHomeCallBacker)
and [GitHub - File](https://github.com/hurricanepkt/SmartHomeCallBacker/blob/main/SmartHomeCallBackerApp/Database/FileContext.cs)

Comment: Try removing `builder.Services.AddScoped<Context>();`. The `.AddDbContext<Context>()` call should already have registered the `Context` as scoped (the default lifetime), so the second registration might screw up something.

Comment: Another thing I'm noticing is the `Database.Migrate();` call inside one of the `OnConfiguring` paths, which most probably generates the exception in question.  As the error says, *"A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is still being configured at this point"*. Which means db services, model etc. are not available there. In general you should only do configuration there, not actions. Similar to   AddSomething and UseSomething in ASPNetCore pipeline. `OnModelCreating` is also a part of the initialization, so database should not be used there as well.

Comment: Thanks that worked.   put attribution on the page [github](https://github.com/hurricanepkt/SmartHomeCallBacker)